# Can early binding be designed to handle method dispatch to avoid runtime dispatching at all?

Tags: java, oop, jvm, compiler-construction, virtual-machine

I'm recently learning JVM on static resolution (early binding) and dynamic dispatch (late binding) topics. I can understand how they work, but the question is why they are designed so. Lots of comparisons mention that early binding is not flexible and late binding is less performant.

Thus, theoretically, I wonder if we can include as much info as possible in .class files, can we realize method dispatch at compile time?

For example, for the following code, the compiler also sees it all, why not just bind the `animal.sound()` call into the `Dog` and include such info in .class file, so later the JVM doesn't have to dispatch any more? Can someone give me an example that such dispatch is impossible to do at compile time?

```
class Animal {
    void sound() {
        System.out.println("Animal makes a sound");
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    void sound() {
        System.out.println("Dog barks");
    }
}
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Dog();
        animal.sound(); // Output: "Dog barks"
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s what early binding means.

Comment: Well, a simple example: `Animal animal = random.nextBoolean() ? new Cat() : new Dog();`

Answer (score 0):

if I need to explain this question in a simple way, you can think of it from real life. Imagine a father with two children, one named Elon and the other named Mark. However, the last name of the father and the two children is Brown. When they all stand in front of you, if you turn to Elon and say, "Hey Brown, how are you?" then Elon will respond. If you do the same to Mark, he will respond, or if you turn to their father and say it, he will respond.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The terms “early binding” and “late binding” are suitable for languages like C++ but not so much for Java, where compile time (in the sense of producing .class files) and link time (where symbolic references between class files are resolved) differ significantly. (Unfortunately this doesn’t keep text books from trying to categorize Java method calls in that way.)

To stay at your example, there is no guaranty that at runtime, when the classes are linked, the `Dog` class still has a method `sound()` overriding the method in `Animal`. The class `Test`, contained in a file `Test.class` can’t make such guarantees about the class `Dog`, contained in the different file `Dog.class` which may stem from a different compiler run.

Such scenarios are not corner cases. Rather, running an application with a newer version of a library or even with a newer Java version without recompiling, happens all the time.¹

That said, it’s important to understand that a late binding call (e.g. via a vtable) is not significantly more expensive than an ordinary call. The actual problem with linking to an unknown target is that the optimizer can’t perform any work to it. Most optimization techniques work best when inlining a call, to use the knowledge about caller and callee when generating the combined code. Since this happens after the linking phase, at runtime in Java, there is no problem with late binding here. The runtime optimizer *does* recognize that the `sound()` call in your example will always end up at `Dog`’s implementation and utilize that knowledge.²

---

¹ there are other scenarios. For example, you can create an optimized runtime image with `jlink`, where module versions are fixed and hence, earlier binding *is* possible.

² Though, in this specific case, the optimizer will usually not run, as the program is too short to benefit from optimizations. Only repeatedly executed code is worth such effort.